# Move navigation.sections into the page.header element in XML?

Tags: magento2, xml

This is my code:

```
    <move element="navigation.sections" destination="page.header" />
```

But the navigation bar disappears then. Whats wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution was to use `header.container`. Found it via console:

`grep -rl "navigation.sections" *` to find out where this gets injected, because its close to the desired destination.

`nano vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml` to find the name of the container in which it gets injected. Suprise - its `header.container` instead of `page.header`.

```
 <move element="navigation.sections" destination="header.container" />
```